# Flutter email sender

Tags: email, flutter

I have this error when I send an email from form in flutter.

```
Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(UNAVAILABLE, defualt mail app not available, null)
```

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<String> attachment = <String>[];
  TextEditingController _subjectController =
      TextEditingController(text: 'ct');
  TextEditingController _bodyController = TextEditingController(
      text: '''  a
  ''');
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scafoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> send() async {
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    final MailOptions mailOptions = MailOptions(
      body: 'Ro',
      subject: 'the Email Subject',
      recipients: ['rodrigo@houlak.com'],
      isHTML: true,

      attachments: [ 'path/to/image.png', ],
    );

    await FlutterMailer.send(mailOptions);

    String platformResponse;

    try {
      await FlutterMailer.send(mailOptions);
      platformResponse = 'success';
    } catch (error) {
      platformResponse = error.toString();
    }

    if (!mounted) return;
    _scafoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text(platformResponse),
    ));
  }
```

Comment: if you are trying it on emulator, it wont work anyway

Answer (score 6):

Adding in AndroidManifest.xml this for me on Android solve the issue:

```
<application .... />
// add queries tag for mailto intent out side of application tag
<queries>
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
    <data android:scheme="mailto" />
  </intent>
</queries>
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue on iPhone, it was caused because I hadn't set up the default iOS default Mail App.

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure the Android Gradle Plugin is higher then 4.1.0 you will find it inside `android\build.gradle` file some thing like this

   dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1' "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version" classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4' }

2 . add this to your  `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` file just after where you add the `<uses-permission>`

```
<queries> <intent> <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" /> <data android:scheme="mailto" /> </intent> </queries>
```

3. run `flutter clean`
4. run `flutter pub get` or you can run your code it will do this for you after that Flutter email sender package should works for you
   this solve the issue for me